# Probabilistic meaning of maximal rectangle under probability distribution function graph

Tags: reference-request, probability-distributions

Let $\xi$ be a random variable with $p(x)$ density function, which is like a normal distribution (i.e. $p(x)$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and decreasing on $[0,\infty)$). Denote by $s$ the maximum area of rectangle inside $p(x)$ and real line:
$$
s = \max\left\{a\cdot|I| \colon a\cdot\chi_I(x)\le p(x)\right\}
$$
where $\chi_I$ is the characteristic function of $I\subset\mathbb{R}$, $|I|$ is the length of interval $I$ and the maximum is taken over all possible combination of $a\in\mathbb{R},\,I\subset\mathbb{R}$ is an interval.
It can be shown that $s$ can be anything from $(0,1]$.

Is there any reference to paper/book/... about this maximal rectangular area ?

Does $s$ represent some probabilistic meaning related to $\xi$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If $\xi$ is symmetric with $E|\xi|=1$, then $s=2\sup_{x>0}xp(x)$ is the supremum of the density $x(2p(x))/E|\xi|$ of the so-called size-biased distribution of $|X|$; see e.g. [Arratia and Goldstein](http://bcf.usc.edu/~larry/papers/pdf/csb.pdf).